# Boost.Spirit compiler error

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-spirit

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
template <typename Iterator>
struct CommandGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type>
{
    CommandGrammar()
        : CommandGrammar::base_type(text)
    {
        using qi::lexeme;
        using qi::char_;
        using qi::space;

        specialSymbols %= (char_('-') | char_('{') | char_('}') 
                | char_('[') | char_(']') | char_('|') | space);
        text %= *space >> lexeme[+(char_ - specialSymbols)] >> *space;
   }

    qi::rule<Iterator, char(), qi::space_type> specialSymbols;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::space_type> text;
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << ">";
    std::string usage;
    std::getline(std::cin, usage);
    CommandGrammar<std::string::const_iterator> commandGrammar;

    std::string::const_iterator iter = usage.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = usage.end();

    std::string result;
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, commandGrammar, qi::space, result);
    if (r && iter == end) {
        std::cout << result;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::string(iter, end) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I need help to find the problem in this code. Here is part of error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal.hpp:14,                                                                                                                          
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:19,                                                                                                                                      
                 from /usr/include/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,                                                                                                                                   
                 from main.cpp:1:                                                                                                                                                                    



/usr/include/boost/fusion/algorithm/query/detail/any.hpp:55:   instantiated from bool boost::fusion::detail::any(const Sequence&, F, Tag) [with Sequence = boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Tag = boost::fusion::forward_traversal_tag]                                                                                                                                                                 
/usr/include/boost/fusion/algorithm/query/any.hpp:30:   instantiated from bool boost::fusion::any(const Sequence&, F) [with Sequence = boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, F = boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_container<boost::spirit::qi::detail::fail_function<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]                            
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/sequence_base.hpp:97:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::sequence_base<Derived, Elements>::parse_impl(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&, mpl_::true_) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Derived = boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, Elements = boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > >]                                                                  
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/operator/sequence_base.hpp:115:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::sequence_base<Derived, Elements>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Attribute = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Derived = boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, Elements = boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > >]                                                                                   
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/detail/parser_binder.hpp:73:   instantiated from bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<Parser, mpl_::bool_<true> >::operator()(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, Parser = boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >]         
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132:   instantiated from static R boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker4<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2, T3>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2, T3) [with FunctionObj = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&]                   
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:   instantiated from void boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&]                                                                                                                     
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::function4(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&]
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:   instantiated from boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&]
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1105:   instantiated from typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<boost::spirit::qi::sequence<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::lexeme_directive<boost::spirit::qi::plus<boost::spirit::qi::difference<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type> > > > >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::kleene<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >, boost::fusion::nil> > > >, mpl_::bool_<true> >, R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&]
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:191:   instantiated from boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3>& boost::spirit::qi::operator%=(boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3>&, const Expr&) [with Expr = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_right, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::dereference, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>&>, 1l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::subscript, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::lexeme>, 0l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::unary_plus, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::minus, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::char_, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&, boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, char(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type>&>, 2l>&>, 1l>&>, 2l>&>, 2l>&, const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::dereference, boost::proto::argsns_::list1<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>&>, 1l>&>, 2l>, Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = std::string(), T2 = boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0l>, T3 = boost::fusion::unused_type]
main.cpp:19:   instantiated from CommandGrammar<Iterator>::CommandGrammar() [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]
main.cpp:31:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:236: error: no match for call to (const boost::function<bool(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<char&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&)>) (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<char&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, const boost::spirit::qi::detail::unused_skipper<boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> > >&)
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1006: note: candidates are: R boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::operator()(T0, T1, T2, T3) const [with R = bool, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<char&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, T3 = const boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >&]
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The attribute of A | B](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/alternative.html) is boost::variant.

If you need to match a lexeme containing any symbol but "special" ones, the following should do this:

```
    text %= lexeme[+~char_("-{}[]|")];
```

(Note that the [parser skips spaces automatically](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parse_api/iterator_api.html), as you passed `qi::space` to `phrase_parse()`, you don't have to skip them explicitly.)